# Save opened Fragments on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have TabHost, which contains activities in there.
I'm setting up these activities via `TabSpec.setContent(intent)` method.

Each activity has some list views. On tap at Listview item I have to open new Fragment (I need to keep Tabs visible. that's why I use fragments). But if I opened fragment and then changes screen rotation, fragment just disappears. Are there any ways to save or restore opened fragments in each tab?

Here is the code how I start fragment in Activity

```
articleFragment = new TabletArticleActivityFragment(articleHeadersList, rubricIdentifier, article.getId(),
getResources().getColor(color.blogs));
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(id.tabletRubricLayoutTest, articleFragment, "articleDetailFragment");
articleFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
ft.addToBackStack("articleDetailFragment").commit();
```